# simple PHP if logic not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to make a simple if else statement but I cannot get the desired results and am obviously using the wrong methods.

This is what I have:

```
if (!$res7 and !$res8) {output one - this should appear if both $res7 and $res8 are empty}

else if (!$res8)  {output two - this should appear if $res8 is empty}

else if (!$res7) {output three - this should appear if $res7 is empty}
```

The outputs show what I desire, can someone help with fixing it? Thanks

EDIT the full code: $res7 and $res8 are results from a MySQL query

`$res8 = $pdo->query($query8);`

```
if (empty($res7) && empty($res8)) {

printf("We currently have no reviews for this park or its attractions. If you have been to %s please take a minute to give your feedback. You don't need to register to leave reviews or ratings. Thank you." . PHP_EOL, $row[name]);
}

elseif (empty($res8)) {

printf("We currently have no attraction reviews for this park. If you have been to %s please take a minute to give your feedback. You don't need to register to leave reviews or ratings. Thank you." . PHP_EOL, $row[name]);

}

elseif (empty($res7)) {

printf("<h3>Park Review</h3>We currently have no reviews for this park as a whole. If you have been to %s please take a minute to give your feedback. You don't need to register to leave reviews or ratings. Thank you." . PHP_EOL, $row[name]);
}

else { 
printf("all good");
}
```

Comment: What are the values for $res7 and $res8? What's happening that shouldn't be?

Comment: What? PHP doesn't have the `and` keyword.

Comment: Try using the empty() method instead of !

Comment: Use && instead of 'and'

Comment: it most certainly does... http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: If the first condition passes are you expecting to see the output from the second and third as well... if so just remove the else's

Comment: @Brian Yes it does, but it is rarely used.

Comment: @brian: yes, it does. `and` and `or` are both valid in PHP, but have a lower operator precedence than `||` and `&&`. consider the used-everywhere `$result = mysql_query(..) or die(mysql_error())` type construct...

Comment: An empty string is still equal true. This might be your problem.

Comment: I have posted the full code now

Comment: @user2574794 - Try doing a `var_dump($res8)` and see what you get - I suspect you'll get a resultset back, though one that doesn't include any results. You need to count how many rows are returned, rather than checking to see if the variable is empty.

Comment: @andrewsi `if($res7->rowCount() < 1){ }` like this? how would I add $res8 to it?

Comment: @user2574794 - You can just replace your if statements with `if (($res7->rowCount() == 0) && ($res8->rowCount() == 0))` and so on.

Comment: That has worked perfectly. If you wanna put it as an answer I will accept. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you're initialising `$res8`

```
$res8 = $pdo->query($query8);
```

At this point, `$res8` is a result set, containing the results of your query. What you're trying to do is check to see if that resultset is empty. You can't call `empty()` on it, because even with no results in it, it's still a resultset, so it's returning FALSE on your call.

What you need to do is using the in-built functions to see how many rows it contains:

```
if ($res8->rowCount() == 0) {
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean empty as `empty` and not as `false`, then do it this way:

```
if (empty($res7) && empty($res8)) {
    // First case
} elseif (empty($res8)) {
    // Second case
} elseif (empty($res7)) {
    // Third case
} else {
    // Not $res7 nor $res8 are empty
}
```

Comment: @3ventic Yes, I've confused it with `is_null` for some reason.

Comment: @Campari: Oh, how I love how consistent PHP is :-P

Comment: @RocketHazmat On the "bright side", it forces you to look at the manual more often than you normally would :)

Comment: @campari thanks for the reply, I have copied it exactly and even when $res7 or $res8 has data it is still going to the final else output. I should say $res7/8 are results directly from a MySQL query, would that effect the code needed?

Comment: @user2574794 - can you edit your question to include your actual code?

Comment: @user2574794 When `$res7` or `$res8` have data, they _should_ go to the final else, as "neither of them are empty" isn't that correct? Also, if your using PDO the query would return an empty array if there are no results, and the `empty` function works with arrays too. So technically it _should_ work.